# Passing parameter from vb.net using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create some application in vb.net that passing parameter to stored procedure in SQL server 2008
I've tried this code, and I'm not sure what should I write next

```
Public Function List(ByVal date As Date) As DataTable
    Dim SPName As String = "usp_Name"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        oConn.Open()
        Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(SPName, oConn)
        cmdSQL.CommandTimeout = 2000
        cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Date").Value = date //im not really sure this is the correct code
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
        da.Fill(dt)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        oConn.Close()
    End Try
    Return dt
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
cmdSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this  code

```
cmdSQL .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date)
```